# Converting this list into Dictionary using Python

Tags: python, list

```
list = ['Name=Sachin\n', 'country=India\n', 'game=cricket\n']
```

I want this list in a dictionary with keys as `Name`, `country`, `game` and values as `Sachin`, `India`, `cricket` as corresponding values. I got this list using `readlines()` from a text file.

Comment: `list` is not a good name for a variable. You will now find it difficult to create lists (not impossible though, I don't want to argue about this). Maybe `athlete` or `athlete_attributes`.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> lst = ['Name=Sachin\n', 'country=India\n', 'game=cricket\n']
>>> result = dict(e.strip().split('=') for e in lst)
>>> print(result)
{'Name': 'Sachin', 'country': 'India', 'game': 'cricket'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another way using regex.

```
>>> lis = ['Name=Sachin\n','country=India\n','game=cricket\n']
>>> dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+)',''.join(lis)))
{'Name': 'Sachin', 'game': 'cricket', 'country': 'India'}
```

Comment: There is always a regex guy around in these kind of questions.

Comment: I certainly hope that's a compliment.  Regex are powerful and well worth knowing.  In many situations they're exactly what you need.  Imagine if someone wrote, "There is always a functional programming guy in these kinds of questions" on your post--kinda rude.

Comment: @ozgur Avinash is *the* regex guy.

Comment: @par Certainly +1 for showing a different perspective. This is why I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 2):

in one line:

```
lst =['Name=Sachin\n','country=India\n','game=cricket\n']

dct = dict( (item.split('=')[0], item.split('=')[1].strip()) for item in lst )
print(dct)

# {'game': 'cricket', 'country': 'India', 'Name': 'Sachin'}
```

note: `list` ist not a good variable name!

`strip()` is called twice which is not all that nice - this may be better:

```
def splt(item):
    sp = item.strip().split('=')
    return sp[0], sp[1]

dct = dict( splt(item) for item in lst )
print(dct)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
my_list = ['Name=Sachin\n', 'country=India\n', 'game=cricket\n']
my_dict = {}

for entry in my_list:
    key, value = entry.strip().split('=')
    my_dict[key] = value

print my_dict
```

This give you the following dictionary:

```
{'country': 'India', 'game': 'cricket', 'Name': 'Sachin'}
```

Note, you should not use a variable name of `list` as this is used as a Python function.

If you are reading from a file, you could do this is follows:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    my_dict = {}
    for entry in f_input:
        key, value = entry.strip().split('=')
        my_dict[key] = value

print my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:  # note: you don't need to call readlines()
        key, value = line.split('=')
        answer[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {
        k: v 
        for k, v in map(
                    lambda x: x.strip().split('='), 
                    yourlist
                    )
    }
```

And as [**Peter Wood** suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602353/converting-this-list-into-dictionary-using-python/32604112#comment53057749_32602353) rename your list variable not to shadow the built-in `list`.